# Editing function inside ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an edit control inside of an `ng-repeat` that is correctly changing boolean values onclick, however, the elements that are hooked to these values via `ng-show` are not showing/hiding.  What is going wrong?

Controller:

```
    $scope.editedAnswers = {};

    $scope.toggleEditAnswer = function(answer) {
      $scope.editedAnswers[answer._id] = !$scope.editedAnswers[answer._id];
      console.log($scope.editedAnswers[answer._id]);
    };

    $scope.updateAnswer = function(answer) {
      answer.$update(function() {
        $location.path('answers/' + answer._id);
      });

      $scope.toggleEditAnswer(answer);
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div class="answers" ng-show="showAnswers">
      <div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
        <div class="answer-info">
          <a ng-show="!editedAnswer[answer._id]" ng-click="toggleEditAnswer(answer)">edit</a>
          <a ng-show="editedAnswer[answer._id]" ng-click="updateAnswer()">save</a>
        </div>

        <div ng-hide="editedAnswer[answer._id]"></div>
        <textarea ng-show="editedAnswer[answer._id]">
        {{answer.content}}
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the problem is that in controller you define `editedAnswers` property, but in HTML you refer to the `editedAnswer` property (without -`s`)

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
<div class="answers" ng-show="showAnswers">
      <div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
        <div class="answer-info">
          <a ng-show="!editedAnswer[answer._id]" ng-click="toggleEditAnswer(answer)">edit</a>
          <a ng-show="editedAnswer[answer._id]" ng-click="updateAnswer()">save</a>
        </div>

        <div ng-hide="editedAnswer[answer._id]"></div>
        <textarea ng-show="editedAnswer[answer._id]">
        {{answer.content}}
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="answers" ng-show="showAnswers">
      <div ng-repeat="answer in answers">
        <div class="answer-info">
          <a ng-show="answer._id != editedAnswer[answer._id]" ng-click="toggleEditAnswer(answer)">edit</a>
          <a ng-show="answer._id == editedAnswer[answer._id]" ng-click="updateAnswer()">save</a>
        </div>

        <div ng-hide="answer._id == editedAnswer[answer._id]"></div>
        <textarea ng-show="answer._id == editedAnswer[answer._id]">
        {{answer.content}}
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In your version you're simply showing if `editedAnswer[answer._id]` exists.

In my edit (which may not be evaluating what you actually want - you may need to change != and == around) I am checking if the current `answer` equals (or not) then `editedAnswer[answer._id]` - I.E `answer._id == editedAnswer[answer._id]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, nothing really changed on the DOM side.